# Xamarin Android Bug: While trying to open a phone dialer the screen splits with the dialer

Tags: android, user-interface, debugging, mobile, xamarin.android

While trying to open a phone dialer the screen splits with the dialer.
How to avoid the splitting of the screen, which is an unwanted behavior.
This issue is only reproducible on Android.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKPib.png)
The challenge here is that'm not able to debug as the issue is not reproducible on the emulator and while trying to build the code directly on the real device I see the "Could not connect to the debugger" box.

```html
private static void HandlePhoneLink(string number)
{
    try
    {
        PhoneDialer.Open(number);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Crashes.TrackError(ex);
    }
}
```

Suggestions to avoid unexpected behavior.
Any clues on where I should look?

Comment: On what device did you test it? What is the Android version?

Comment: On Galaxy S22, we see a split screen, It should only show the phone number on the dialler.
On Pixel 7Pro, nothing happens when we click on the card on the phone.

Comment: Android version is 13

Comment: Have you tested on other devices(e.g. android emulator)? Does this problem occur on other devices as well?

Comment: I was debugging on the emulator and was able to see 2nd scenario where nothing happens on the click. 
While debugging found that the PhoneDialer in Xamarin.Essential has this IsSupported property which is set to false and the digit count is 11(Example 15555555555) but the user set number is length is 10.